# Will IBM Bluemix talk to Labview

Tags: ibm-cloud, labview

Using this link (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-bluemix-diy-iot-wearable-app/) I am transferring data from Wiced Broadcom device to cloud. However I need to get this information into Labview. Will IBM Bluemix 'talk' to Labview?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. It is described in this tutorialt: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/national-instruments-labview-for-the-iot-foundation/

I have tried this personally and was able to connect.